# Using fstream in struct, errors

Tags: c++, constructor, fstream

I'm trying to initialize a file output stream inside a struct. The file that should be created has a name that i'd like to define in the main function, i.e:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct str {
std::ofstream fs;

};

int main() {
    str G;
    G.fs("hello.txt",std::ios::app);
}
```

This gives me:
error: no match for call to '(std::fstream {aka std::basic_fstream}) (const char [10], const openmode&)'|

How to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

The initialization constructor can't be used this way. Try this:

```
int main() {
    str G;
    G.fs.open("hello.txt",std::ios::app);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad! If this was helpful, please consider upvoting the answer and marking it "accepted" :-)